# Vertical alignment inside a simple div

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

This is a very simple question, but after a few hours surfing the web I've realized that probably I'm not getting the concept.

I have:

```
<style>
 #more{width:190px; height:44px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding-bottom:3px;vertical-align:middle;}
</style>

 <div id='more'> My text </div>
```

This does not center the "My text" vertically. How can I center the text vertically?

Thanks a million

Comment: You might be interested in this article - http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: There are very few, but also very different ways to center something vertically in CSS. The method to use often depends on the circumstances. Such as: Do you expect your text to wrap (consist of several lines)? How is the DIV itself positioned? Does it have a fixed size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `line-height` equal to the height of your div.

```
line-height: 44px;
```

**NB:** this will only work on text in a single line.

Comment: +1: note this works with a single line and only on the text, (but that is the OP's requirement ;)

Comment: This only works, if the text doesn't wrap (consist of multiple lines).

Comment: Not sure we need 3 comments saying the exact same thing... I'll add it to my answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `display: table-cell;` to be able to center the text vertically.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSaTj/) demo.

Comment: This can break the layout, pepending on how the DIV is positioned.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: IE8 does support it. IE7 doesn't.

Comment: @RoToRa: that's why I said **under** IE8 :), but you're right, it's ambigous. So let's say it works correctly on IE8 or newer :).